Python COM connection issue when using win32 for Excel and Outlook
I am trying to take a screenshot of an excel sheet that contains real-time data and put it into an email to send out. When I have the excel sheet closed that program runs fine however when I have the excel sheet already open it does not work and comes up with an error saying the application is already open.
I want the program to be able to take the screenshot while the sheet is open.
# Check if the Excel file exists
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    print(f"The Excel file does not exist: {file_path}")
else:
    # Initialize Excel
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application",pythoncom.CoInitialize())
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False

    # Attempt to export the images
    try:
        excel2img.export_img(file_path, output_file1, "Runs!", 'P2:AC79')
        excel2img.export_img(file_path, output_file2, "Runs!", 'C2:M53')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while exporting the images: {e}")


# Initialize Outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')


Here is the error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects\Dated Trades\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 84, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects\Dated Trades\.venv\Email winner.py", line 61, in <module>
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "PycharmProjects\Dated Trades\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 118, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch, userName, clsctx)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "PycharmProjects\Dated Trades\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 104, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "PycharmProjects\Dated Trades\.venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)

Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried different win32 settings such as obtaining the active window.
